# Form a dictionary that key is from a list, value is the occurrence of items in another list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

Given two lists with the same length:

```
List1 = ['a','b','c','d','b','a','b','c']
List2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
```

I want output the a dict as:

```
dic = {'a':['1','6'], 'b':['2','5','7'], 'c':['3','8'], 'd':['4']}
```

How to implement it in Python? Thanks!

Comment: Did you attempt a solution yourself?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` function to create a list of (in python 3.X an iterator) columns and use  [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method (or `collections.defaultdict`) to create a desire dictionary :

```
>>> List1 = ['a','b','c','d','b','a','b','c']
>>> List2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
>>> 
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in zip(List1,List2):
...   d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
... 
>>> d
{'a': ['1', '6'], 'c': ['3', '8'], 'b': ['2', '5', '7'], 'd': ['4']}
```

And if you care about the order you can use `collections.OrderedDict` :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> for i,j in zip(List1,List2):
...   d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
... 
>>> d
OrderedDict([('a', ['1', '6']), ('b', ['2', '5', '7']), ('c', ['3', '8']), ('d', ['4'])])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) method. Example -

```
>>> List1 = ['a','b','c','d','b','a','b','c']
>>> List2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
>>>
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> outd = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x,y in zip(List1,List2):
...     outd[x].append(y)
...
>>> outd
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'c': ['3', '8'], 'd': ['4'], 'b': ['2', '5', '7'], 'a': ['1', '6']})
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution using `itertools.groupby`. In-fact, groupby seems more natural solution as it is more explicit in what it tends to achieve.
To summarize, combine both the lists and group them based on the first item in the list.

**Implementation**

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {k: map(itemgetter(1), v)
     for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(List1, List2)),
                         key = itemgetter(0))}
```

**Output**

```
{'a': ['1', '6'], 'c': ['3', '8'], 'b': ['2', '5', '7'], 'd': ['4']}
```

Off-course as others have mentioned, if the order is important, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`

**Implementation**

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict((k, map(itemgetter(1), v))
                for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(List1, List2)),
                                    key = itemgetter(0)))
```

**Output**

```
OrderedDict([('a', ['1', '6']), ('b', ['2', '5', '7']), ('c', ['3', '8']), ('d', ['4'])])
```